# Getting multiple list of properties from a List of Objects in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Considering I have a list of objects `List<Emp>` where `Emp` has 3 properties `name`, `id`, and `age`. What is the fastest way to get 3 lists like `List<String> names`, `List<String> ids`, and `List<Integer> ages`.

The simplest I could think of is to iterate over the entire list and keep adding to these 3 lists. But, I was wondering if there is an easier way to do it with Java 8 streams?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe iterating over the entire list would be the quickest option... anything with streams I think would require 3 separate streams, thus 3 iterations compared to one

Comment: `The simplest I could think of is to iterate over the entire list and keep adding to these 3 lists.` - This is the simplest way. Do not try to make it unnecessarily complex using `Stream`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very interesting question, however, there is no dedicated collector to handle such use case.

All you can is to use 3 iterations (Streams) respectively:

```
List<String> names = employees.stream().map(Emp::name).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> ids = employees.stream().map(Emp::id).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> ages = employees.stream().map(Emp::age).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

**Edit - write the own collector**: you can use the overloaded method [`Stream::collect(Supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) to implement your own collector doing what you need:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> newMap = employees.stream().collect(
    HashMap::new,                                               // Supplier of the Map
    (map, emp) -> {                                             // BiConsumer accumulator
        map.compute("names", remappingFunction(emp.getName())); 
        map.compute("ages", remappingFunction(emp.getAge()));
        map.compute("ids", remappingFunction(emp.getId()));
    },
    (map1, map2) -> {}                                          // BiConsumer combiner
);
```

Practically, all it does is extracting the wanted value (`name`, `age`...) and adding it to the `List` under the specific key `"names"`, `"ages"` etc. using the method [`Map::compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) that allows to compute a new value based on the existing (`null` by default if the key has not been used).

The `remappingFunction` that actually creates a new `List` or adds a value looks like:

```
private static BiFunction<String, List<Object>, List<Object>> remappingFunction(Object object) {
    return (key, list) -> {
        if (list == null)
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(object);
        return list;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 Stream has some API to split the list into partition, such as: 
1. `Collectros.partitioningBy(..)` - which create two partitions based on some `Predicate` and return `Map<Boolean, List<>>` with values;
2. `Collectors.groupingBy()` - which allows to group stream by some key and return resulting Map.

But, this is not really your case, since you want to put all properties of the `Emp` object to different `Lists`. I'm not sure that this can be achieved with such API, maybe with some dirty workarounds.

So, yes, the cleanest way will be to iterate through the `Emp` list and out all properties to the three Lists manually, as you have proposed.